# Array populating issue in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: So it was really obvious, I needed the "Preserve" modifer for the Redim statement.

I'm trying to write a UDF in Excel VBA which takes a column of prices and selects the *n* highest/lowest buys/sells (marked in the adjacent column), and outputs 'yes' or nothing depending on whether a given cell meets those criteria.

As an example, for *n* = 2 the input could look something like this:

Price Type Result
150  buy         yes
170  sell
146  sell        yes
167  buy
125  buy
164  sell        yes

So I'm counting through the price column, putting each price in either a 'buy' or 'sell' array, but for some reason when I look at the results only the last entries are showing up correctly, with the rest of the entries = 0.

Here's the code I've got:

```
Function included(prices As Range, entry As Range)
n = 2
bc = 1                'counter for the buys
sc = 1                'counter for the sells
Ub = 1                'upper bound for buys
Us = 1                'upper bound for sells
Dim b() As Double     'dynamic array for buys
Dim s() As Double     'dynamic array for sells

'collect the buys and the sells into two arrays
For i = 1 To prices.Rows.Count
    amt = prices(i).Value
    If prices(i).Offset(0, 1) = "buy" Then   'add to buy list
        ReDim b(1 To Ub)                     'reapply length
        b(bc) = amt                          'add the entry
        Ub = UBound(b) + 1                   'add one to the length
        bc = bc + 1                          'increase the counter by 1
    ElseIf prices(i).Offset(0, 1) = "sell" Then
        'add to s
        ReDim s(1 To Us)
        s(sc) = amt
        Us = UBound(s) + 1
        sc = sc + 1
    Else
        MsgBox "nothing"
    End If
Next

'check the resulting arrays (only the last value in b() and s() print out)
For i = 1 To UBound(b)
    If b(i) <> 0 Then
        MsgBox b(i)
    End If
Next
For i = 1 To UBound(s)
    If s(i) <> 0 Then
        MsgBox s(i)
    End If
Next

'still to do: 
' sort the buy and sell arrays in ascending and descending order respectively
' truncate the arrays to length n   
' check if entry is in one of the resulting arrays

End Function
```

I'm really new to VBA (and a mere Python novice), so maybe it's something obvious? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: when you ReDim, the array is emptied and that is why you are only seeing the last entry.  To keep the values, use 'preserve' as in `Redim Preserve b(1 To Ub)`

Comment: Note that you can answer you own question (it is even [highly recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)) and accept it. This way, you can share your knowledge with the community and kind of *close* the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [msdn library entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for `ReDim`, the `Preserve` modifier needs to be included, so the code now reads `ReDim Preserve b(1 To Ub)`. Without the modifier the statement was emptying the array.